# How to make Preview open all PDF documents in full screen

Tags: macos, pdf, preview.app

When I open pdf files with the Preview in MacOS the scale of the window doesn't cover the whole desktop. It's smaller and I always need to make an open window wider and longer in order to view files comfortably (also I'm using a monitor which is connected to my laptop). I've tried to find the corresponding setting in the preferences menu, tried to change some, but the default appearance didn't change.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble with PDFs is they open at 100% of their own size, not your screen's size [I know that's irritating]

I've found the quickest way to deal with it is just double-click the top bar, which will at least size it to fit in one direction. Double-clicking any corner [when you see the cursor change to a double arrow] will fill the screen, but not expand the image to completely fill the window.

Comment: That's a nice way to deal with the problem, thanks